# Which past version of Netbeans IDE that has lightness almost equal or better than Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: java, ide, eclipse, netbeans

Currently, I'm a long Eclipse user because my past and current companies always deal with eclipse. Recently I met some example java codes created using netbeans. I downloaded and tried Netbeans 7.x and 6.9.x, but they're more heavier and eating memory resources than Eclipse Indigo.

So anyone know which past version of Netbeans IDE that has lightness almost equal to or better than Eclipse Indigo (3.7) but can support Java SDK v1.6?

Comment: It doesn't matter which IDE you use. Import the project into Eclipse.

Comment: I can't do that from eclipse.  Also the netbeans project is java EE web project. I don't think java EE projects in both eclipse and netbeans are compatible each other.

Comment: The IDE you choose has nothing to do with the code, you can use any project in any IDE.

Comment: @sevenseacat: no, there is a thing called Java EE web project (in eclipse, it's called Dynamic Web Project). It will integrate with apache tomcat or other supported application server and you can deploy and run/debug directly from eclipse or netbeans.

Comment: If you use maven you can run an `eclipse:eclipse` on the project and it will set it up for you. Netbeans and Eclipse are almost interchangeable. Deploying to tomcat/jetty,etc.. and running it from the IDE can be done with ease too.

Comment: I never tried maven before, can you recommend me a maven tutorial link for eclipse:eclipse thing?

Answer (score 3):

Whether one IDE is more lightweight than another is pretty subjective.  Do you have the identical features running etc?  Even then it's not a like for like comparison.  Couple of workarounds:

1. The two IDEs both feature importers that will allow you to bounce projects back an forth - most of my projects run in all three major IDEs.
2. You can performance tune your IDE, take a look at what Java heap settings they both start with and run a quick GC analysis on them when you do project work.  You've be amazed what a few command line parameter changes can do.
3. Good hardware is comparatively cheap.  SSD Drive + 8 GB of RAM should see almost any IDE happy.

Comment: +1 for SSD and suitable amount of RAM. Both are terrific investments for a programer.

Comment: Three major IDEs being? I can only think of Eclipse and Netbeans.

Comment: I'd guess IntelliJ?

Comment: I usually open around 60 tabs in eclipse. At minimum I expect there is no lag when typing in the IDE editor, switching tab, or showing dialog/window in the IDE. Currently I use company laptop, so SSD and RAM upgrade are not options, although that sounds a really good idea if I have my own laptop for works.

Comment: IntelliJ was the 3rd major IDE :-)

Comment: @suud - cripes - tell your manager to get you better kit - you can actually calculate the value of a new laptop vs your *expensive* wasted time :-).

Comment: I don't think my boss will grant me to update ram or even ssd (which is very costly), it's an uncommon request. Asking a replacement of a broken mouse is still acceptable.